# jQuery Slider doesn't pick up elements on line break

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi i have a basic jQuery slider, I have a number of years which I want to slider across with the use of my arrows. Firstly I want any overflow to be hidden, which is not working as I require it to.

I was expecting `overflow:hidden` on my `<ul class="yearslist">` to hide the overflow that goes onto the next line however this doesn't seem to work instead the other li elements are shown below.

Anyway as the slider moves from left to right it doesn't show the years on the bottom line on the top line as it moves along.

Would love any help in making this work perfectly!

I've created a simple [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wdECw/) or view my code below:

index.html

```
<div class="sixteen columns" id="years">
        <div id="years_arrows">
            <span class="nav_arrows" id="NavigateBackward"><img src="http://www.designofsignage.com/application/symbol/building/image/600x600/arrow-left-circle.jpg"/></span>
         <span class="nav_arrows aaa" id="NavigateForward"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/45/Right-facing-Arrow-icon.jpg" /></span>
       <div id="slider">
        <div id="yearslistwrapper">
                <ul class="yearslist">
                    <li><a href="#">2003</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">2004</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">2004</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">2005</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">2006</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">2007</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">2008</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">2009</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">2010</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">2011</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">2012</a></li>                       
                    <li><a href="#">2013</a></li>
                </ul> <!-- END UL yearslist -->
            </div> <!--End slider-->

                            </div> <!-- End years_arrows div -->
```

style.css

```
#years {
    background-color:#CCC;
    height:50px;
    word-spacing:100px;
}

#yearslistwrapper, .yearslist {
    padding-top:10px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.yearslist {
    overflow:hidden;
    display:inline; 
}

.yearslist li {
 display:inline;   
}
}

.yearslist a {
    color:#000; 
    text-decoration:none;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:bold;
}

.yearslist a:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
}

/** BG For Span on Nav Arrows **/ 
.nav_arrows { 
    height:100%;
    max-width:5%;
}

#years_arrows {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

#years_arrows img {
    width:50%;
    height:70%;
    padding-top:10px;
}

#NavigateBackward {
    float:left;

}

#NavigateForward {
    float:right;
}
```

js.js

```
// SLIDE YEARS

$(document).ready (Initialize);

function Initialize(){
    InitList();
}

var moveLeft = false;
var moveRight = false;

var left = function() {
    if (moveLeft)
        $(".yearslist").animate({ "marginLeft": "-=5px" }, 50, 'linear', left);
};

var right = function() {
    if(moveRight)
        $(".yearslist").animate({ "marginLeft": "+=5px" }, 50, 'linear', right);
};

function InitList() {
    $("span#NavigateBackward").hover(
        function() { moveLeft=true; left(); },
        function() { moveLeft=false; }
    );
    $("span#NavigateForward").hover(
        function() { moveRight=true; right(); },
        function() { moveRight=false; }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right I solved the problem.

What I did was add the CSS attribute `white-space: nowrap;`

.yearslist {
    overflow:hidden;
    display:inline; 
    white-space: nowrap;
}

Or view [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wdECw/1/)